# Ubuntu 18.04.3 grub fails to install on USB

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I have been trying to Install 18.04.3 in dual boot mode. My latest attempt is to install on a USB memory stick of 128gb.  The install ends with an error message basically saying "Cannot install Grub".

I ran the install from an Ubuntu Live USB stick with the main hard drive removed, so the only drive available for install was the 128gb USB.

The only success I have had is to an old Hard Drive running from a USB connection. However, there are errors even so and the performance is far too slow to be useable. Hence wish to run from a fast USB. 
An attempt to upgrade to Kernal 5 killed the working Ubuntu 18.04 I did have on a separate partition of the main drive.

Does anyone have any ideas to fix, please? PC Boot is via UEFI and the main drive (when connected) is a Samsung SSD which has Windows 10 on an encrypted drive.

Comment: Maybe it will work according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Answer (score 3):

Did you crate "EFI Partition" when you installed Ubuntu?

This partition is where the installer will install grub during installation on a UEFI system, but without that partition, grub can't be installed. To solve this, you need to re-partition your drive.

Install Ubuntu again and create 1 partition at least 300 MB, then click the check boxes for "boot" and "esp".

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The USB drive had a complete install including EFI partition created by the Ubuntu ISO.  I have since changed PC and now have Ubuntu 19.10 dual booting with Win 10. However there were still error messages which I think were caused by PPA entries which did not have Release Notes for 19.10 according to a "Software updater" error message. I have removed these and so far the original error message no longer appears when I close down, which is when the error messages would appear. Not sure this is the answer as there were Release notes for the previous Ubuntu LTS release installed on USB drive